# Ordering of query parameters in pyramid.request object

Tags: python, pyramid, http-request, http-request-parameters

I am writing a few REST APIs.

In one of those I want to know order in which the parameters were mentioned in the query string.

Right now, I am accessing query params using

```
request.params
```

This returns a nested-multi-dict. 
But I don't think the keys are ordered correctly.

Any other way, I can get ordered-dict?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.params`, `request.GET` and `request.POST` are ordered [MultiDicts](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/interfaces.html#pyramid.interfaces.IMultiDict), so you can use `items()` method:

```
from pyramid.request import Request

req = Request.blank('http://gdzies.w.pl/ala/ma/kota?q=1&q=2&w=3&w=4&q=5&a=0')
print req.params.items()
```

The output:

```
[(u'q', u'1'), (u'q', u'2'), (u'w', u'3'), (u'w', u'4'), (u'q', u'5'), (u'a', u'0')]
```